# How to do this (nginx) in apache2 .htaccess?

Tags: apache2, nginx, .htaccess

```
location /.well-known/webfinger {
   add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
   return 301 https://mastodon.bitsnbytes.chat/$request_uri;
}
```

Is it possible to convert this Nginx into Apache2 `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.well-known/webfinger.*)$ https://mastodon.mydomain.tld/$1 [L,R=301]
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Answer (score 1):

In Apache / `.htaccess` this would be something like:

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"

RedirectMatch 301 ^/(\.well-known/webfinger.*) https://mastodon.bitsnbytes.chat/$1
```